# Retrieve your password from admin panel does not work

Tags: administration, magento-1.9.2.0, password-recovery

I've forgotten my admin login pass and using `.../index.php/admin/index/forgotpassword` does not do anything. I do not get any email! How to fix this.

Edit:

By debugging the `...app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\controllers\IndexControll‌​‌​‌​er.php` I noticed in line 225 `public function forgotpasswordAction()` the  `$params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();` is empty! As it does not wait to enter the email address. In other words, this function checks the `$params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();` before loading the forgotpassword form for entering an email!

Comment: can you debug the code???

Comment: In which file specifically you mean?

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\surtikart\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\controllers\IndexController.php in this check forgotpasswordAction()  but 1st backup this file.

Comment: if not find any solution so please check you email server configuration.

Comment: check the email detials here. System->config->System->Email sending option.

Comment: In settings I have "
Disable Email Communications- No", "Host-localhost", "Port-25" and "Set Return-Path-Yes"

Comment: Host : smtp.gmail.com Port : 465 or 587 check this setting. if your mail server is gmail

Comment: other mail are working or not in your system??

Comment: Yes,  for customers is working but for admin forgot pass, no!

Comment: can you debug this file? C:\xampp\htdocs\surtikart\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\controllers\IndexControll‌​er.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36955/discussion-between-zinat-and-ajay-patel).